# Detect mobile device if http post request

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, user-agent

Is there a way to know mobile device if http post request was done programmatically.
E.g. on my android Im doing the following thing:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "12312"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "234"));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Is there a way to know that it was a andriod device that sent this request? I understand I can send additional data here to identify the device. The question is: if post request was done this way is there a way to understand that it was done from andriod device (like by using UserAgent)?

Server that accepts the requests is written in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "User-Agent" HTTP header, however it can be spoofed or not set at all, although all modern browser implement this header. Some useful info can be found on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)